# List Item with options

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to do something like this picture with react-native?

I'll have a list of items and each one can be clicked in the right button (the 3 dots in my example) and access more options, like View/Edit, Delete, etc...

[image: List made with ionic]

I tried looking into the LIST component options, but could not find something to do the same or something similar.

Comment: I don't think there is such a component. But it can be easily implemented by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MikeP. ! I'm starting with react-native, so I don't think I'll be able to do so (not now). I found something using swipe in an item list, but it's a separated component too. I was wondering if the language have something native to give the user options to a specific item in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, you need to deign it by yourselt, here is some rough idea:

```
const [showOptions, setShowOptions ] = useState(false);
const [itemIdSelected, setItemIdSelected = useState(); //so react know which item is         
selected when you click the three dots button

const Data = [{id:.....},.....]; //your data for the list items

const showOptionsHandler = (itemId)=>{
setOptionsShown(true);
setItemIdSelected(itemId);
};

return(

...
<Flatlist
...
data={Data}
renderItem(({item})=>{
    //render the item componet..

    <TouchableHighlight onPress = {()=>{showOptionsHandler(item.id)}}>
        <Ionicons ... />
    </TouchableHighlight>
/>
})

{showOptions && <YourOwnComponentToShowTheOptions />}
//you need to design your own component with the options, which should be 
some       
touchable components, and when pressed, do something for the item selected 
with the 
help of the state 'itemIdSelected'

)
```

Comment: Thank you Wu! It gives me some information to think about! The reason for my question was to see if we have something native as we have with IONIC. I might also use swipe to create it...